# for funtcion and atr function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

i'm newbie in for function and ta.atr() function

my idea is
Long condition 1: Price is upper >=30%
Long condition 2: Minimum 7 last bar has ATR < 5%
Long condition 3: Previous bar is above EMA 10
Long condition 4: Previous bar is ATR >5%

Short condition 1:Price is down >=30%
Short condition 2:Minimum 7 last bar has ATR < 5%
Short condition 3:Previous bar is below EMA 10
Short condition 4:Previous bar is ATR >5%

and my code is

```
    //@version=5
strategy(title="ATR-based Long/Short Trading Strategy", overlay=true)

// Input variables
length = input.int(title="ATR Lookback Length", defval=7, minval=1)
atrLength = input.int(title="ATR Length", defval=10, minval=1)
atrPercent = input.float(title="ATR Percent", defval=5, minval=1, maxval=50) / 100

// Calculate ATR
atr = ta.atr(1)
atr_ma = ta.sma(atr, atrLength)

// Calculate conditions
priceChange = (close - close[length]) / close[length] * 100
atr_break = close > atr_ma * (1 + atrPercent)
price_above_ema = close > ta.ema(close, 10)
num_bars_atr = 0
for i = 1 to length
    if ta.atr(i) < atr_ma * atrPercent
        num_bars_atr := i
        break

// Buy condition
buy_condition = (priceChange >= 30) and (num_bars_atr >= length) and (price_above_ema) and (atr_break)

// Sell condition
sell_condition = (priceChange <= -30) and (num_bars_atr >= length) and (not price_above_ema) and (not atr_break)

// Buy and sell logic
if buy_condition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if sell_condition
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

and tradingview has bug when it run it. i don't know how to fix it.
The line error is line 19 --> if ta.atr(i) < atr_ma * atrPercent
error show is:

> Cannot call 'ta.atr' with argument 'length'='i'. An argument of
> 'series int' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's get something straight first.

**What is a software bug?** [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug).

> A software bug is an error, flaw or fault in the design, development,
> or operation of computer software that causes it to produce an
> incorrect or unexpected result, or to behave in unintended ways.

What you have is not a bug. You are not using the function correctly. `ta.atr()` expects a `simple int` as the error message says. This means these type of variables:

- do not change during script execution
- are unknown at compile time

You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html#) to learn more about the variable types.

You are calling the `ta.atr()` function in a loop and changing its `length` value. Therefore, the compiler complains rightfully so.

If you want to count the occurrences of a condition in the last x bars, you can use the method described [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-condition-in-the-last-x-bars).

Comment: What you have is not a bug --> agree
Maybe I'm not smart enough, after reading the docs I've been told, I still haven't figured out how to fix the above error. If any member can read it. Please help fix the above code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

**Can I use a variable length in functions?**

You can use a “series int” length (so a length that varies from bar to bar) in the following Pine functions: alma(), bb(), bbw(), cci(), change(), cmo(), cog(), correlation(), dev(), falling(), highest(), highestbars(), linreg(), lowest(), lowestbars(), mfi(), mom(), percentile_linear_interpolation(), percentile_nearest_rank(), percentrank(), rising(), roc(), sma(), stdev(), stoch(), sum(), variance(), vwma(), wma() and wpr().

**The Functions Allowing Series As Length script by alexgrover provides versions** of the ema(), atr(), lsma(), variance(), covariance(), stdev() and correlation() functions.

**Script URL**
https://www.tradingview.com/script/kY5hhjA7-Functions-Allowing-Series-As-Length-PineCoders-FAQ/